# PHP script not sending/receiving email

Tags: php, html

I have a site with a form that is suppose to send an email to my company and another to the user that filled out the form.  I have loaded the site with all of the additional files to the server, but when I fill out the form to test it an error pops up saying "Not Found".  I am using the GET method of PHP to handle it.  I am new to PHP, and Web design in general.  Thank you.

```
<?php
//Function that sends the email to the person who submitted the form
function send_email(){
//This sends an email to the person who submitted the form
// email fields: to, from, subject. Put your values here!
$sendermail = 'company@email.com';
$from = "Company<".$sendermail.">";
$to = $_GET['email'];
$subject = 'Product Information';
$message = "A member of our sales team will be getting back to you shortly.  Thank you for your interest in our great line of products."."\n\n"."Best Regards,"."\n\n"."The Team";
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\n";
$headers .= 'From: '. $from . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: '. $sendermail. "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

$ok = @mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

//This sends the contents of the form submission to the website owner
$sendermail2 = $_GET['email'];
$from2 = $_GET['first-name'].' '.$_GET['last-name'].' <'.$sendermail2.'>';
$to2 = 'company@email.com';
$subject2 = 'A customer submission from the product page';
$message2 = "Name: ". $_GET['first-name'] ." ". $_GET['last-name'] ."\n\n". "Company: ". $_GET['company'] ."\n\n". "Email: ". $_GET['first-name'] ."\n\n". "Interest: ".$_GET['Interest'];
$headers2  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers2 .= 'Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\n";
$headers2 .= 'From: '. $from2 . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: '. $sendermail2. "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

$ok2 = @mail($to2, $subject2, $message2, $headers2);
}
return send_email();
?>
```

...and this code is in the body of the HTML page.

```
<FORM ACTION="http://www.server.com/html/form_process.php" METHOD=GET>
```

Comment: What mail server are you running?

Comment: Apache/2.0.52 (Red Hat) Server

Comment: Apache is the webserver.  What MAIL server are you running?  The php mail function doesn't magically send emails, it hooks up with an SMTP server like Postfix for example.

Comment: How about removing the error suppression (`@`) in front of the mail function?

Comment: Please excuse my ignorance, but how do I find that out?  Would that be handled through the Web server or is that an entirely separate deal?

Comment: @Jeremiah Mail server is a totally separate deal, yes. Postfix is a good option for linux servers.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for your Red Hat Server:

```
sudo yum install postfix
```

Subsequently:

```
sudo echo "sendmail_from = me@example.com" >> /your/directory/php.ini
```

And finally:

```
sudo echo "sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f me@example.com" >> /your/directory/php.ini
```

Replace /your/directory/php.ini with your real php.ini directory and me@example.com with the email address you want and restart apache, php and postfix, or directly the server.

Comment: I hardly understand any of this answer.  I'm sure it's me and not you.  Would it be possible to get an explanation that is easier to understand from a beginner's point of view?  Thank you.

Comment: Yes, you just connect to the server via SSH (you can use PuTTY) and run the commands that I have written.

Answer (score 0):

A not found error usually means that you are sending the form to the wrong URL. Check the Url you are sending to and the path to the php file to see if they are correct

Comment: The URL is exactly how it is in relation to the path.  So I'm pretty sure it's not that.